# Why XSLT Transformation Output has trailing number?

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am transforming my XML into another XML File and applying XSLT transformation, However the output of transformation always has trailing number 1.

Here is my code

```
        /**
        ** Input XML 
        */
        $xml = new \DOMDocument;
        $xml->load($file1);
        /**
        ** XSLT File 
        **/
        $xsl = new \DOMDocument;
        $xsl->loadXML($file2);
        /**
        ** Combine and Transform XML and XSLT 
        **/
        $proc = new \XSLTProcessor;
        $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 
        $transformedOutPut = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

        return print_r($transformedOutPut);
```

Here is my XML Input,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

and I have an XSLT File like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <catalognew>
    <container-title>My Data</container-title>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <cdnew>
      <titlenew><xsl:value-of select="title"/></titlenew>
      <artistnew><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></artistnew>
    </cdnew>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </catalognew>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the output result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalognew>
    <container-title>My Data</container-title>
    <cdnew>
        <titlenew>Empire Burlesque</titlenew>
        <artistnew>Bob Dylan</artistnew>
    </cdnew>
</catalognew>
1
```

I wonder why there is an extra line break above the output and a trailing number 1 at the end of the file,

I hope someone can help me it's my first time using this features.

Comment: Does this happen regardless of the input?

Comment: You probably want `print_r()` to return a string, so add true as the second argument - `return print_r($transformedOutPut, true); `

Comment: @NigelRen wow, thank you very much, didnt know it has a parameter for that.

Comment: thank you very much, you saved me 1hour of investigation